# Can I avoid g++ surround _stdcall with __attribute__ string

Tags: attributes, g++, stdcall

I use MinGW's g++ to preprocess my file which has the following function:

```
[call_as(ReadAt)]
    HRESULT _stdcall RemoteReadAt(
        [in] ULARGE_INTEGER ulOffset,
        [out, size_is(cb), length_is(*pcbRead)]
        byte *pv,
        [in] ULONG cb,
        [out] ULONG *pcbRead);
```

The preprocess output is:

```
[call_as(ReadAt)] 
    HRESULT __attribute__((__stdcall__)) RemoteReadAt( 
        [in] ULARGE_INTEGER ulOffset, 
        [out, size_is(cb), length_is(*pcbRead)] 
        byte *pv, 
        [in] ULONG cb, 
        [out] ULONG *pcbRead);
```

Is there a g++ option that avoids changing the 2nd line in the output? Please assume that I won't have access to the file so I am looking for a g++ option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the g++ option: `-D_stdcall=_stdcall`